# Invalid alignment value (Producer: 'LLVM14.0.0git' Reader: 'LLVM 13.0.0git')

Tags: c++, ubuntu, llvm, webassembly, emscripten

I try to build wasm on my ubuntu desktop. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 I tried to install llvm-14 in terminal. But it didn't work. Error is here:

**Invalid alignment value (Producer: 'LLVM14.0.0git' Reader: 'LLVM 13.0.0git')**

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. I updated my emsdk version to 3.1.13